# How do I randomly generate numbers with Lua for Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have this simple game that generates a math problem from this, but it is very inefficient as I have to manually make all the problems myself.

Does anyone know some code better than this or direct me to a good tutorial on how to set this up? Thank you.

```
local M = {}

M["times"] = {
    {
        question="6 x 5",  --The question.
        answers={"30", "11", "29", "20"},  --Array of possible answers.
        answer=1   --Which one from the above array is the correct answer.
    },
}

return M
```

Update:

```
{
    a = math.random( 1, 20 ),
    b = math.random( 1, 20 ),
    question = a * b,
    answer = math.random( m, n )
}
```

I thought this would work, but I get this error in the console:

`mathQuestions.lua:55: attempt to perform arithmetic on global 'a' (a nil value)`

Update #2

```
--mathQuestions.lua
M["times"] = {

    local rnd = function (x) return math.random(1,x) end
    M.times = {}
    local numQuestions = 10 -- how many questions in your database
    for i=1,numQuestions do
        local obj =
        {
            left=math.random(1,10),
            right=math.random(1,10),
            answers={rnd(100), rnd(100), rnd(100), rnd(100)},
            answerIndex=rnd(4) -- will override answer[answerIndex] later
        }
        obj.answer = obj.left * obj.right
        obj.answers[obj.answerIndex] = obj.answer
        M.times[i] = obj
    end

}
```

I get this error:

`ERROR: Failed to execute new ( params ) function on 'game'`

`mathQuestions.lua:121: unexpected symbol near 'local'`

Comment: Does anyone know some code better than this or direct me to a good tutorial on how to set this up?

Comment: Please post lines around 121 and mark which one is 121 in your update

Comment: @Schollii `local rnd = function (x) return math.random(1,x) end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
local rnd = function (x) return math.random(1,x) end
M.times = {}
local numQuestions = 10 -- how many questions in your database
for i=1,numQuestions do
    local obj =
    {
        left=math.random(1,10),
        right=math.random(1,10),
        answers={rnd(100), rnd(100), rnd(100), rnd(100)},
        answerIndex=rnd(4) -- will override answer[answerIndex] later
    }
    obj.answer = obj.left * obj.right
    obj.answers[obj.answerIndex] = obj.answer
    M.times[i] = obj
end
```

The only tricky part there is `obj.answer`: you can't do the multiplication inside the table definition (like `answer = a*b` in your updated question) because left and right (a and b) are then globals that do not exist, and if you did `answer = obj.a*obj.b` then you also have problem that obj does not yet exist (it hasn't been created yet).

Comment: Wow that looks really good and complicated for me! Can you take a look at my update and tell me what you think?

Comment: Added explanations why your update gives you the nil error, hth.

Comment: Thanks for writing back. Now I understand why my code won't work. I added the code that you provided, but I got a different error, hope I can still get some help, really new to lua/corona.

Comment: You have invalid syntax: your first line is M.times={ then you close the bracket after everything. Look at my code, the bracket closes immediately to create an empty table the you add stuff to the table.

Comment: Oh ok I did just like you said, and I think it worked but now it gives me this error: `game.lua:93: bad argument #2 to 'newText' (string expected, got nil)`

Comment: game.lua Line 93: `local questionText = display.newText(questionGroup, questions[currentQuestion].question, 0,0, chalkfFont, 34 )`

Comment: @crentist this is not a discussion forum it is a QA site. Clearly the error you are getting is a separate issue from your original question so you should mark this as solved and try to fix this remaining problem and if you still have trouble open a new question and show what you tried. Don't give up you're almost there!

Comment: Sorry now that I see your other question you just posted it is clear that the error in your last comment was because I forgot to put the question field in my answer, but with the comment format I couldn't see clearly. Apologies.